# PC crashes after moving

Tags: windows-8, audio, freeze

When plugging/unplugging something from the audio section of the MoBo, the PC freezes, without even the BSOD. Any idea of the reason?

Maybe related but sometimes I get a random BSOD (apparently without reason) which I'm investigating.

---

EDIT: After 2 MS complete memchecks, nothing has been detected. 
Furthermore I discovered that any kind of movement of the computer case may freeze it. At this point maybe the problem is not the jack, but its movement...

Comment: do a test of your ram with memtest or the MS ram diagnostic tools, and reinstall your mobo chipset and audio drivers/codecs. try a system file check with 'sfc.exe /SCANNOW'. if all come back clean, may be time for a mobo replace, but make sure your ram tests fine first and foremost.

Comment: This could be a problem with it shorting. Do you have audio on the front and back, and does the problem persist with both

Comment: @DaveRook - I have both, but the problems come only from the back

Comment: I assume this is fixed to the motherboard as well?

Comment: You will be better off asking 2 questions, one about the jack, the other about the RAM. Since your title is about the jack, I'd remove the question about RAM and ask a new question about the RAM.

Comment: @DaveRook - yes, it is fixed to the mobo

Comment: @LambertoBasti - is this a custom built computer by you?

Comment: @CarlB - Yes. May this be a problem?

Comment: @LambertoBasti - I had a similar problem when my son built his, he used more stand offs than the board required and those extra were causing grounding/shorting issues causing BSOD. It sounds similar to your system's symtoms.

Comment: I used only the ones that come out with the mobo!

Comment: @CarlB - You were right! i put only 4 stand offs and now i can even throw it out of the windows and it'll remain on! 
Answer to the question!

Comment: @LambertoBasti - Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like an issue I had in my past when the inccorect amount of stand offs were used. Be sure to review the installation of the required stand off points. Putting too many or too little will allow the board to run the risk of shorting out or being improperly grounded. This can cause immediate shutdow, to BSOD and even death of the motherboard.

Too little - there are points on the board where grounding is required to occur.
Too many - touches point of the board that should not be touched by metal.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is due to shorting.

To find out,
1) Buy a mini jack cable (male on one end, female on other (see image below, they're very cheap)),
2) turn PC off,
3) plug the cable in to the faulting jack port,
4) turn PC on,
5) when OS loaded plug your audio into the new cable and see if the same issue persists.

[image]

Comment: I'm doing a complete memchek from MS tools right now; I'll try this as soon as possible